# FFMPEG Cutting Commercials puts audio out of sync

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, h.264

Ubuntu 14.04.1 with the real ffmpeg loaded (same problem with the avconv version).

I'm trying to take files created in MythTV with a HDPVR, cut the commercials and put the video into an MP4 container for use with MythRoku.

the command

`ffmpeg -i $file -acodec copy -vcodec copy -f mp4 file.mp4`

Works fine. Once I update the database, I can watch the file in MythRoku or Plex.

However, when I try to cut out the commercials, the audio gets out of sync by just over 1 second (audio delayed) whenever I cut past the 0 mark.  Totem Video player and VLC both play the resulting video fine, but I can see a "hitch" at the beginning while they are syncing the audio, so I know the information on the audio sync is in the file somewhere.  Mythroku and Plex both are out of sync when playing the file.  The MythTV Frontend player actually does play it correctly, and I can hear the "hitch" as it syncs the audio.

After hours of reading posts and playing with settings, I've got it down to this:

If I say:

`ffmpeg -i $file -acodec copy -vcodec copy -f mp4 -ss 0 -t <anything> out.mp4`

The file is fine, plays both locally and in MythRoku/Plex

But if I advance the start any amount - even 1 second - audio is out of sync

`ffmpeg -i $file -acodec copy -vcodec copy -f mp4 -ss 1 -t <anything> out.mp4`

I've tried splitting the video (as mp4) and audio (as ac3) first, splitting them separately, and then putting them back together as the last step, but I get the same results.

The information is in the file - Totem, VLC and the Frontend all can figure it out.  How can I get ffmpeg to figure out the sync and write the file so it's correct?

Original file:

```
mythtv@marvin:~$ mediainfo /var/lib/mythtv/recordings/2225_20140824001500.mpg
General
ID                                       : 0 (0x0)
Complete name                            :     /var/lib/mythtv/recordings/2225_20140824001500.mpg
Format                                   : MPEG-TS
File size                                : 4.03 GiB
Duration                                 : 1h 45mn
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 5 491 Kbps

Video
ID                                       : 4113 (0x1011)
Menu ID                                  : 1 (0x1)
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L4.0
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 4 frames
Format settings, GOP                     : M=4, N=32
Codec ID                                 : 27
Duration                                 : 1h 45mn
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 4 831 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 20.0 Mbps
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
Height                                   : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate                               : 59.940 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.087
Stream size                              : 3.55 GiB (88%)
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709

Audio
ID                                       : 4352 (0x1100)
Menu ID                                  : 1 (0x1)
Format                                   : AC-3
Format/Info                              : Audio Coding 3
Mode extension                           : CM (complete main)
Format settings, Endianness              : Big
Codec ID                                 : 129
Duration                                 : 1h 45mn
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 384 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Bit depth                                : 16 bits
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Delay relative to video                  : -6ms
Stream size                              : 289 MiB (7%)
```

File cut from 0:

```
mythtv@marvin:~$ mediainfo 2225_20140824001500_1.mp4
General
Complete name                            : 2225_20140824001500_1.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 58.5 MiB
Duration                                 : 1mn 45s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 4 676 Kbps
Writing application                      : Lavf54.63.104

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L4.0
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 4 frames
Format settings, GOP                     : M=4, N=32
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 1mn 45s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 4 281 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 20.0 Mbps
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
Height                                   : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Frame rate                               : 59.940 fps
Minimum frame rate                       : 59.920 fps
Maximum frame rate                       : 59.960 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.077
Stream size                              : 53.6 MiB (92%)
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AC-3
Format/Info                              : Audio Coding 3
Mode extension                           : CM (complete main)
Format settings, Endianness              : Big
Codec ID                                 : ac-3
Duration                                 : 1mn 45s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 384 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Bit depth                                : 16 bits
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 4.81 MiB (8%)
```

File cut from 1 second with audio sync problem:

```
mythtv@marvin:~$ mediainfo 2225_20140824001500_2.mp4
General
Complete name                            : 2225_20140824001500_2.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 68.0 MiB
Duration                                 : 2mn 0s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 4 750 Kbps
Writing application                      : Lavf54.63.104

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L4.0
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 4 frames
Format settings, GOP                     : M=4, N=32
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 1mn 58s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 4 394 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 20.0 Mbps
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
Height                                   : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Frame rate                               : 59.940 fps
Minimum frame rate                       : 59.920 fps
Maximum frame rate                       : 59.960 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.080
Stream size                              : 62.3 MiB (92%)
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AC-3
Format/Info                              : Audio Coding 3
Mode extension                           : CM (complete main)
Format settings, Endianness              : Big
Codec ID                                 : ac-3
Duration                                 : 2mn 0s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 384 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Bit depth                                : 16 bits
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 5.49 MiB (8%)
```

Comment: In case someone finds this, I found the answer.  I wasn't making the cuts at keyframes.  As soon as I changed to marking everything at a keyframe, all my cuts worked fine and audio stayed in sync.